# How we can Update ExpandableListview with Update List API instantly without loosing position of ExpandableListview view item?

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I have an `Expendable ListView` showing data on home screen after hitting API, now I am changing status of item. Firstly, if I am changing status of an item , it should be change the status of all item of same group,  and  update `ListView` without loosing position of an item.

How can I get return type data from Update API and instantly set on item and Update list instantly without loosing items position.

```
 public class GroupsAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
public ArrayList<Group> groupArrayListResponse;
int finaltext;

JobInfoAdapter jobInfoAdapter;
private int source = 1;
private int destination = 1;
private Child child_mModelClass;
Group group_mModelClass;
private  int close;
PdfSpinnerAdapter pdfSpinnerAdapter;
String[] splitStr, splitStr2;
String date1, date2;
String[] timeIn, timeOut;
Group groupClass;
JSONObject jsonObjForJobInfo;
ArrayList<String> fdata;

public GroupsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
    this.context = context;
    this.groupArrayListResponse = groups;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child> chList = groupArrayListResponse.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    child_mModelClass = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    final ChildViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_home_item, null);
        holder = new ChildViewHolder();
        holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView);
        holder.previousImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.previousImage);
        holder.statusBar_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusBar_mTextView);
        holder.document_OnHomeAdap_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.document_OnHomeAdap_mTextView);
        holder.pickup_OnHomeAdap_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pickup_OnHomeAdap_mTextView);
        holder.sourceLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sourceLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout);
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout);
        holder.destinationLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.destinationLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout);
        holder.deliver_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliver_mTextView);
        holder.date_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_mTextView);
        holder.scrollingView_mView = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scrollingView_mView);
        holder.mainViewLayoutmLneraLyaout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainViewLayoutmLneraLyaout);
        holder.childView_mLimearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childView_mLimearLayout);
        holder.nestedList_mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nestedList_mRecyclerView);
        holder.title_onHomFragAdap_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_onHomFragAdap_mTextView);
        holder.weight_onHomFragAdap_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.weight_onHomFragAdap_mTextView);
        holder.instruction_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.instruction_mTextView);
        holder.from_cust_city_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.from_cust_city_mTextView);
        holder.destinationLocation_OnHomeAdap_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.destinationLocation_OnHomeAdap_mTextView);
        holder.pin_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pin_mTextView);
        holder.size_onHomFragAdap_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.size_onHomFragAdap_mTextView);
        holder.timeSlot_mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeSlot_mTextView);
        holder.timeSlot_mRElativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeSlot_mRElativeLayout);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.scrollingView_mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(child_mModelClass.getColors()[groupPosition]));
    jobInfoAdapter = new JobInfoAdapter(child_mModelClass.getKeyOfJobInfo_mArrayList(), child_mModelClass.getValueOfJobInfo_mArrayList());
    holder.linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    holder.nestedList_mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(holder.linearLayoutManager);
    holder.nestedList_mRecyclerView.setAdapter(jobInfoAdapter);

    // Setting DOCUMENTADAPTER
    if (child_mModelClass.getDocument_mArrayList().size() == 0) {
        pdfSpinnerAdapter = new PdfSpinnerAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, child_mModelClass.getDocument_mArrayList());
        holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(pdfSpinnerAdapter);
        holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView.setCursorVisible(false);
        holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView.setText(String.valueOf(child_mModelClass.getDocument_mArrayList().size()));
    } else {
        pdfSpinnerAdapter = new PdfSpinnerAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, child_mModelClass.getDocument_mArrayList());
        holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(pdfSpinnerAdapter);
        holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView.setCursorVisible(false);
        holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView.setText(String.valueOf(child_mModelClass.getDocument_mArrayList().size()));
    }

    int index = HomeFragment.recycler_onHome_Act_mExpandableListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = HomeFragment.recycler_onHome_Act_mExpandableListView.getChildAt(childPosition);
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - HomeFragment.recycler_onHome_Act_mExpandableListView.getPaddingTop());
    HomeFragment.recycler_onHome_Act_mExpandableListView.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);

    if (child_mModelClass.getFrom_time_in() != null && (child_mModelClass.getFrom_time_out() != null)) {
        String str = child_mModelClass.getFrom_time_in();
        splitStr = str.split("\\s+");
        String str2 = child_mModelClass.getFrom_time_out();
        if (str2 != null) {
            splitStr2 = str2.split("\\s+");
            date1 = splitStr[1];
            date2 = splitStr2[1];
            timeIn = date1.split(":");
            timeOut = date2.split(":");
            holder.date_mTextView.setText(timeIn[0] + ":" + timeIn[1] + "  " + timeOut[0] + ":" + timeOut[1]);
        }
    }
    if (child_mModelClass.getTo_cust_name() != null) {
        holder.deliver_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getTo_cust_name().toString());
    } else {
    }

    if (child_mModelClass.getTitle() != null) {
        holder.title_onHomFragAdap_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getTitle().toString());
    } else {
    }
    if (child_mModelClass.getInstructions() != null) {
        holder.instruction_mTextView.setText("Notes: " + child_mModelClass.getInstructions().toString());
    } else {
    }
    if (child_mModelClass.getFrom_cust_name() != null) {
        holder.pickup_OnHomeAdap_mTextView.setText("Pickup " + child_mModelClass.getFrom_cust_name().toString());
    } else {
    }
    if (child_mModelClass.getFrom_cust_city() != null) {
        holder.from_cust_city_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getFrom_cust_city().toString());
    } else {
    }
    if (child_mModelClass.getSize() != null) {
        holder.size_onHomFragAdap_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getSize());
    } else {
    }
    holder.destinationLocation_OnHomeAdap_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getTo_cust_address1().toString() + " " + child_mModelClass.getTo_cust_city() + ", " + child_mModelClass.getFrom_cust_state());
    if (child_mModelClass.getTimeslot() == null || child_mModelClass.getPin() == null) {
        holder.timeSlot_mRElativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.timeSlot_mRElativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.timeSlot_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getTimeslot().toString());
        holder.pin_mTextView.setText("Pin" + " " + child_mModelClass.getPin().toString());
    }
    try {
        String weight = child_mModelClass.getWeight().toString();
        finaltext = Integer.parseInt(weight) / 1000;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    final String chkk = String.valueOf(finaltext);
    if (chkk.equals("0")) {
        holder.weight_onHomFragAdap_mTextView.setText("0");
    } else {
        holder.weight_onHomFragAdap_mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(chkk) + "t");
    }
    if (child_mModelClass.getStatus_code().equalsIgnoreCase("ACCEPT")) {
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1475A9"));
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getStatus_code());
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setEnabled(false);
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.disabled_bkg);
        holder.previousImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.disabled__left_arrow);
    } else if (child_mModelClass.getStatus_code().equalsIgnoreCase("ARRIVE PICKUP")) {
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33CC33"));
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getStatus_code());
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setEnabled(true);
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_light_gray);
        holder.previousImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_left_arrow);
    } else if (child_mModelClass.getStatus_code().equalsIgnoreCase("DEPART PICKUP")) {
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#009933"));
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getStatus_code());
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setEnabled(true);
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_light_gray);
        holder.previousImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_left_arrow);
    } else if (child_mModelClass.getStatus_code().equalsIgnoreCase("ARRIVE DELIVER")) {
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9966FF"));
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getStatus_code());
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setEnabled(true);
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_light_gray);
        holder.previousImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_left_arrow);
    } else if (child_mModelClass.getStatus_code().equalsIgnoreCase("DEPART DELIVER")) {
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9966FF"));
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getStatus_code());
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setEnabled(true);
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_light_gray);
        holder.previousImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_left_arrow);
    } else if (child_mModelClass.getStatus_code().equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETE")) {
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9966FF"));
        holder.statusBar_mTextView.setText(child_mModelClass.getStatus_code());
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setEnabled(false);
        holder.previousStatus_mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_light_gray);
        holder.previousImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_left_arrow);
    }

    holder.statusBar_mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.e("GroupStatus", "-Next2-" + view.getId());
            Log.e("GroupStatus", "-Next1-" + view.getTag());
            Log.e("GroupStatus", "-Next-" + group_mModelClass.getLegListAccToGroup_mArrayList());
            GlobalClass.setLegID(child_mModelClass.getLeg_id());
            Log.e("StatusIDDD", "-12-" + GlobalClass.getLegListAccToGroup_mArrayaList().get(0));
            if (child_mModelClass.getStatus_code().equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETE")) {
                groupArrayListResponse.remove(groupPosition);
            }
            if (child_mModelClass.getStatus_code().equalsIgnoreCase("ARRIVE DELIVER")) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, DeliveryAcceptanceActivity.class));
            } else if (groupPosition == 0) {
                changeStatus(group_mModelClass.getLegListAccToGroup_mArrayList());
            }
        }
    });


    if (groupPosition == 0) {
        group_mModelClass.getLegListAccToGroup_mArrayList();
    }


    holder.previousImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("GroupPosition", "-Previous-" + group_mModelClass.getLegListAccToGroup_mArrayList());
            previousStatus(group_mModelClass.getLegListAccToGroup_mArrayList());
        }
    });
    holder.document_OnHomeAdap_mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (source == 1) {
                source = 2;
                holder.sourceLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (source == 2) {
                source = 1;
                holder.sourceLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.pickup_OnHomeAdap_mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (source == 1) {
                source = 2;
                holder.sourceLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (source == 2) {
                source = 1;
                holder.sourceLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
    holder.deliver_mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (destination == 1) {
                destination = 2;
                holder.destinationLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (destination == 2) {
                destination = 1;
                holder.destinationLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });


    close = 1;
    holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (close == 1) {
                holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
                close = 2;
            } else if (close == 2) {
                holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();
                close = 1;
            }
        }
    });

    if (close == 2) {
        holder.docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                close = 1;
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child> chList = groupArrayListResponse.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groupArrayListResponse.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groupArrayListResponse.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    group_mModelClass = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.header_item, null);
    }

    final Object v = getGroup(groupPosition);

    TextView textSeparator = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
    textSeparator.setText(group_mModelClass.getName());
    HomeFragment.recycler_onHome_Act_mExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

private void changeStatus(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
    hmap.put("useraccesstoken", GlobalClass.getAccessToken());
    hmap.put("legid", String.valueOf(arrayList));
    AppInterface service = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
    final Call<JsonObject> resListCall = service.UpdateLegStatus(hmap);
    resListCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, retrofit2.Response<JsonObject> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                if (group_mModelClass.getLegListAccToGroup_mArrayList() != null) {
                    group_mModelClass.getLegListAccToGroup_mArrayList().clear();
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                HomeFragment.GettingsMainLegLIst();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}


private void previousStatus(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
    hmap.put("useraccesstoken", GlobalClass.getAccessToken());
    hmap.put("legid", String.valueOf(arrayList));
    AppInterface service = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
    final Call<PreviousStatus> resListCall = service.PreviousStatus(hmap);

    resListCall.enqueue(new Callback<PreviousStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PreviousStatus> call, retrofit2.Response<PreviousStatus> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

               Log.e("PREVIOUSSUCCESS", "" + response.isSuccessful());
                HomeFragment.GettingsMainLegLIst();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PreviousStatus> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}


class GroupViewHolder {
    TextView name;
}

class ChildViewHolder {
    TextView statusBar_mTextView, document_OnHomeAdap_mTextView, pickup_OnHomeAdap_mTextView, deliver_mTextView,
            date_mTextView, title_onHomFragAdap_mTextView, weight_onHomFragAdap_mTextView, instruction_mTextView,
            from_cust_city_mTextView, destinationLocation_OnHomeAdap_mTextView, pin_mTextView, size_onHomFragAdap_mTextView,
            timeSlot_mTextView;
    ImageView previousImage;
    View scrollingView_mView;
    AutoCompleteTextView docSpinner_mAutoCompleteTextView;
    RelativeLayout sourceLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout, destinationLocation_OnHomeAdap_mRelativeLayout,
            previousStatus_mRelativeLayout, timeSlot_mRElativeLayout;
    LinearLayout mainViewLayoutmLneraLyaout, childView_mLimearLayout;
    RecyclerView nestedList_mRecyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

}
```

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, when i am hitting Update API , under response method, am hitting again GettingData Api before calling this API i am clearing  the response List Adapter and sets again, so that adapter again  sets and i am loosing position. i know this is wrong approach to update it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko , i am just again calling Home fragment ApI, instead of  updating listview

Comment: Only you know what `calling Home fragment ApI` means. Do you set a new adapter to your `RecyclerVIew`?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, its not new Adapter, its same adater ,  i am just refreshing it again by calling Api, and before calling clearing list of previous data

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  , can you please check code, in code there is a method of name ChangeStatus(), in that method i am hitting Api , and getting resposne , how could i get it and upadte it instantly.
Sorry for bad explaination, its my first question here

Comment: the reason probably is that you first clear the list, and then only request new one. In this case you will for sure loose position, etc. You should rework your logic

Answer (score 0):

Override these all functions

It helps me to solve this

```
    @Override
    //counts the number of parent items so the list knows how many times calls getGroupView() method
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mParent.size();
    }

    @Override
    //counts the number of children items so the list knows how many times calls getChildView() method
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return mParent.get(i).getArrayChildren().size();
    }

    @Override
    //gets the title of each parent/group
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return mParent.get(i).getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    //gets the name of each item
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return mParent.get(i).getArrayChildren().get(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        /* used to make the notifyDataSetChanged() method work */
        super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }
```